# VBA Plots not showing up with correct X-labels

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to grab data from the worksheet called "Finances".

For some reason my code doesn't label the x tick axis values as the device names from the C column that i pulled from. This is my code:

```
Sub MakeFinanceChart()

Dim rX1 As Range rY1 As Range, rX2 As Range, rY2 As Range, rX3 As Range, rY3 As Range, rX4 As Range, rY4 As Range, rX5 As Range, rY5 As Range, rX6 As Range, rY6 As Range
Dim rChartPos As Range
Dim chtO As ChartObject

Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("F5:F80")
Set rX2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("J5:J80")
Set rX3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("L5:L80")
Set rX4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("P5:P80")
Set rX5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("T5:T80")
Set rX6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("X5:X80")

Set rChartPos = Worksheets("PLOTS").Range("O2:X28") ' location and dimensions of the chart
With rChartPos
Set chtO = .Parent.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
chtO.Name = "Finance Plots"
End With

'Plot the Whole Finance CHART

With chtO.Chart

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    ' First series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX1
        .Values = rY1
        .Name = "A"
    End With

    ' Second series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX2
        .Values = rY2
         .Name = "B"
   End With

    ' Third series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX3
        .Values = rY3
         .Name = "C"
   End With

   ' Fourth series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX4
        .Values = rY4
        .Name = "D"
    End With

    ' Fifth series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX5
        .Values = rY5
         .Name = "E"
   End With

    ' Sixth Series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX6
        .Values = rY6
         .Name = "F"
   End With


    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Finance Plot"

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using xlLine for the ChartType. xlScatter is for a numerical x-axis; xlLine is for categories on the x-axis.

Comment: YES! This worked perfectly. How can I get the x-axis to display all of the values because right now its showing every 5th value